# Generate PDF from Blob String

Tags: apex, visualforce

My VF Page Code ----

```
<apex:page controller="GenaratePDF_Controller" contentType="application/pdf" >
      <script>
        window.location.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,{!match1}";
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

My Apex Code-----

```
public class GenaratePDF_Controller {
    
     public String getMatch1() {
        StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'Blob_String2' LIMIT 1];
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(sr.Body);
    }
}
```

ScreenShot---

[image: Error That Occurring]

My Blob String-----

```
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
```

Comment: Why not just use `<apex:page action="{!URLFOR($Resource.Blob_String2)}"></apex:page>`? You don't need any Apex at all.

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid base64 pdf? I tried a few online tools but it doesn't seem to want to decode properly. If you're using a static resource why don't you just save the pdf there?